# Prove {$v_1,v_2,w$} is a basis for vector space _V_

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A problem from my textbook states:

Let {$v_1,v_2,v_3$} be a basis for a vector space $V$. Prove that, if $w$ is not in $sp(v_1,v_2)$, then {$v_1,v_2,w$} is also a basis for $V$.

---

Assume {$v_1,v_2,v_3$} is a basis for a vector space $V$, and $w \notin sp(v_1,v_2)$.

With the given assumptions, $w$ is not necessarily contained in $V$.

Therefore, {$v_1,v_2,w$} is not necessarily a basis for $V$.

---

Is there something wrong with my logic, or is the question badly worded?

Comment: I guess it is badly worded and it should be read as $$w\in V,w\notin sp(v_1,v_2) \dots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, they assume all the time that any vector mentioned will be in $V$, because $V$ is the only thing within the scope of the problem. As far as the problem goes, there's no other vector space in sight. It would be different if $V$ were a subspace of a larger vector space, for instance.

Comment: So it would be okay to assume that $w\in V$ as @KfSsOc did in his answer?

Comment: @JonSnow Yes, definitely. You'll see this type of question a lot, where $w \in V$ is assumed because there's no other place $w$ could be that makes sense.

Comment: Oh okay, I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v \in V$, thus: $v = a_1v_1+a_2v_2+a_3v_3$, and $w \in V$, thus $w = b_1v_1+b_2v_2+b_3v_3$. Thus $b_3 \neq 0$ since $w \notin \text{span}{(v_1,v_2)}$. This means $v_3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,w$, and therefore $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v_1,v_2,w$, proving they span $V$, linear independence can be easily established.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, as the question is stated, your logic is valid. It is however in my experience the case that such questions will (particularly when having multiple parts) list assumptions such as $w \in V$ prior to any actual question being asked. Perhaps including the textbook, and location of the question therein would be helpful.

As the other answer states, if there's no explicit mention of where $w$ comes from, it's a safe bet to assume it belongs to the only vector space in scope, especially for the purposes of answering the question for credit in an assignment.

Comment: The textbook is Linear Algebra (3rd edition) by Fraleigh and Beauregard, and the question is from section 3.2, problem 32. 
I did read the questions preceding this one, but the only one that mentions $w$ also says that a basis for $V$ is {$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$}, so I don't think it is related.
I will, however, assume $w\in V$ like the other answers state.